# Unexpected result using angular-routes

Tags: angularjs

I am working through the book "MEAN web development by Amos Haviv" and I am not getting the expected results in a particular portion of the chapter on AngularJS routing. This section of the book is on setting up angular routing for a single page application. In short I expect that when I navigate to http://localhost:3000, the AngularJS router should redirect the request to http://localhost:300/#!/ and to see two text boxes from one of my views.

I have followed the code exactly as it is given in the book and been over the code several times to check if I missed something. The process in the book is as follows:
- configure the application routing in the public/application.js file
- use ngRoute module to manage routes in a public/example/example.client.routes.js file
- including scripts in the view.html file and adding 
- lastly running the server

my application.js file:

```
var mainApplicationModuleName = 'mean';

var mainApplicationModule = angular.module(mainApplicationModuleName,
    ['ngRoute', 'example']);

    mainApplicationModule.config(['$locationProvider',
    function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    }
    ]);

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, [mainApplicationModuleName]);
});
```

my example.client.routes.js file:

```
angular.module('example').config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
when('/', {
templateUrl: 'example/views/example.client.view.html'
}).
otherwise({
redirectTo: '/'
});
}
]);
```

my example.client.view.html file:

```
<section ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <input type="text" id="text1" ng-model="name">
    <input type="text" id="text2" ng-model="name">
</section>
```

In my index.ejs file i have included `<section ng-view></section>` and also script tags for example.client.routes.js, example.client.controller.js, example.client.module.js in addition to angular.js and angular-route.js

When I start the node server I see the following requests happening in my console log:

> The server is running 
>   GET / 304 32.496 ms - - 
>   GET /img/logo.png 404 11.459 ms - 25 
>   GET /lib/angular/angular.js 304 15.638 ms - - 
>   GET /lib/angular-route/angular-route.js 304 12.533 ms - - 
>   GET /example/example.client.module.js 304 14.989 ms - - 
>   GET /example/controllers/example.client.controller.js 304 15.237 ms - - 
>   GET /example/config/example.client.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20routes.js 404 15.647 ms - 76

According to the book I should get redirected to http://localhost:3000/#!/ and should see my two forms which are part of my view, however this is not what happens. The page just remains at http://localhost:3000/ and i don't see the forms. In the log above I can't figure out why the route shows as

> GET /example/config/example.client.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20routes.js

and not as

> GET /example/config/example.client.routes.js

Comment: Are you manually adding script tags to index html file or are they added by a task runner like gulp/grunt or a bundler like webpack?

Comment: @charlietfl manually added

Comment: Sure there aren't erroneous spaces in routes.js script tag src? Or wacky quotes? Will also see errors thrown in browser console preventing app to bootstrap properly due to missing file

Comment: @charlietfl had that script tag in index.html running over a line which added the space. Working now. Thank you!